# Java 16bit CRC packet validation

Tags: java, validation, crc, crc16

I have an Avl Packet that I'm recieving through GPRS from a Device.

The protocol manual says the packet has a 16bit CRC on the last 4 bytes and a source code for CRC calculation is given:

```
public static int getCrc16(Byte[] buffer) {
    return getCrc16(buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0xA001, 0);
    }

public synchronized static int getCrc16(Byte[] buffer, int offset, int bufLen, int polynom, int preset) {
    preset &= 0xFFFF;
    polynom &= 0xFFFF;
    int crc = preset;
    for (int i = 0; i < bufLen; i++) {
        int data = buffer[i + offset] & 0xFF;
        crc ^= data;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ polynom;
            } else {
                crc = crc >> 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return crc & 0xFFFF;
}
```

So I get the CRC number the packet sends me,then I call getCrc16 for the Byte array in which I have stored the packet and then compare the two numbers right??

Here is the code I use inside my program:

```
public static String toBinaryString(byte n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("00000000");
    for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
        if (((n >> bit) & 1) > 0) {
            sb.setCharAt(7 - bit, '1');
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

    int CalculatedCRC = getCrc16(AvlPacket);
    System.out.println("Calculated CRC= " + CalculatedCRC);

    int index = (AvlPacket.length)-4;
    String BinaryRecievedCRC = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        BinaryRecievedCRC+= toBinaryString(AvlPacket[index]);
        index+=1;
    }

    int RecievedCRC = Integer.parseInt(BinaryRecievedCRC, 2);
    System.out.println("Recieved CRC= " + RecievedCRC);
```

toBinaryString() converts a byte to it's binary from and puts it into a string!

So I calculate the CRC through getCrc16() given to me from the manual.Then take an index 4 bytes before the end of the packet so I can read the last 4 bytes and get the CRC sent with the packet!

The for loop takes each of the last bytes and with toBinaryString() combines all them in binary form and into a String!So I got something like 0000000000000000101011011101001 (The manual states that first two bytes are always zeroes because its a 16bit CRC)

So I just parse the Binary String into a signed int and Compare the two CRCs...!

Yet I get Results like :

Calculated CRC= 21395
-----Recieved CRC= 30416

or

Calculated CRC= 56084
-----Recieved CRC= 10504

I've tested with many packets and they can't all have loss of data..And I'm parsing the data too so I know that the data I get is correct!

What am I missing in all this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

The problem was that the Packet had 8 other bytes before getting into the Data part!
So I had to exclude those first 8 bytes along with the last 4 bytes of the sent CRC before calculating the CRC!

Now the numbers agree and the above code is correct with the exception that the for loop in the getCrc16 function starts from i=8 (so as to skip the first 8 bytes of the packet which do no belong to the Data part!)

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: In my case its should be i=8. However that depends on the data you receive! Check the device data manual to see what data it sends you and check which part of that data should be in the CrC calculation.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something wrong with the documentation wording (or your understanding of it). If there is a 16-Bit CRC in a packet, its most likely occupying *two* bytes, not *four* (in binary form). If it were a decimal, even four bytes wouldn't suffice (you would need 5 didgts to store it as unsigned decimal string).

Your code shows you do conversions (but I can't see what kind of conversion its supposed to do):

```
BinaryRecievedCRC+= toBinaryString(AvlPacket[index]);
```

I would expect the CRC to be store in the data in binary form, so I assume the only thing you need to figure out are which endianess is used and where the CRC is stored in the data.

Edit: Judging from your comment you would need to extract the CRC like this:

```
public int getCRC(byte[] data, int index) {
    return ((data[index] & 0xFF) << 8)) | (data[index + 1] & 0xFF);
}
```

Comment: The CRC is on the last two of the 4 bytes as written in the manual:

16 bit CRC value of data (Integer). Polynomial 0xA001 (value is
always 4 Bytes 00 00 XX XX ; where XX XX is 16 bit CRC)

//I am converting the bytes into a binary string and then I'm parsing the string as a singed int...The endianess is Big as with everything else in the packet

Comment: So then why do you not follow that in your code? I see you appending something to a *String* (variable names should start with a lower case letter in java btw). Your description does not really match the code you show...

Comment: The toBinaryString function within the for loop just makes the 4 bytes into a big Binary String so I can parse it after to the signed int...The code call for "getCrc16" and gets the calculated CRC from the function given in the manual.Then sets an index 4 bytes before the end of the packet so I can get with th for loop and the "toBinaryString" function the Binary form of the CRC sent and then I parse the Binary CRC into an int and compare them!What part do you think is wrong?

Comment: What exactly is toBinaryString() doing? And why *append* this to a string? I think thats where the misunderstanding is. The getCrc16() you show to calculate the CRC simply returns an int. Yet you do something complicated (for which you do not show the code) with the received data instead of just *taking* the bytes and put the int back together (like my getCRC16() example shows). You do some weird conversion with the loop for (j...). Why? What gave you that idea? I'm almost *certain* that this is wrong.

Comment: Your code doesnt return a value at all :/

Give me a sec,I'll edit the post to contain toBinaryString().Bear in mind that I've used it already and does what it is supposed to.Take a byte and write  it's binary form into o String!

Comment: I see. Thats a pretty *roundabout* way to convert four bytes into an int. What do you mean my code doesn't return a value at all? (The method is declared to return an int, how can it return *nothing*? getCRC16(length-2) should return the exact same value you get with your toBinaryString() conversion). Oh well, at least I can confirm your conversion from packet data to CRC16 *does* what it is supposed to do. My guess now would be that the CRC should be calculated over the packet *excluding* the CRC itself (try altering: getCrc16(buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0xA001, 0); to buffer.length-2 or -4).

Comment: I tried with .length-2 or -4 but it just decreases the CRC calculated..it doesn't make it equal with the recieved one.You method returns the same number as I do with .toBinaryString() so at least that works indeed..But still I calculate different CRC with the one I get from the Device

Comment: Since the last 4 bytes contain the CRC on the last two and the first two are zeroes,then buffer.length-2 and buffer.length-4 shouldn't give me the same value??Because they don't..

Answer (score 0):

> So I get the CRC number the packet sends me,then I call getCrc16 for
>   the Byte array in which I have stored the packet and then compare the
>   two numbers right??

Wrong. You calculate the CRC over the entire message, *including the CRC bytes,* and the result should be zero.

Comment: Yet the Result is not Zero even if I calculate the CRC bytes..!I tried excluding them but the calculated CRC just decreases in value,it's not equal to the recieved one...Do you see any bugs to the code above?